# Set new FQDN to access Sharepoint, but shortcuts link to NetBIOS name

Tags: sharepoint-server, https

Recently I installed Sharepoint Server 2019 and have attempted to switch from the NetBIOS name to a FQDN. I've set up https in the IIS Manager and set the default zone URL of Sharepoint - 80 to https://sharepoint.example.com

Accessing it works, logging in works and overall it works good, however, the shortcuts (links to OneDrive for example) it reverts back to http://sharepoint/my instead of https://sharepoint.example.com/my

Did I set up something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!

For other people who may run into this issue:
Login to the Sharepoint Central Administration Portal.
Then go to: Application Management --> Manager service applications --> User Profile Service Application --> Setup My Sites (under My Site Settings).
In here, set the My Site Host location to the FQDN that you want it to be.

That fixed this issue for me.